# Can't set background fill of DataGridColumnHeader in UWP Toolkit

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Can anyone explain why I'm unable to set the background `Fill` on the `DataGridColumnHeader` template?

Looking at the source here: https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/DataGrid/DataGrid.xaml , specifically the line:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRectangle" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{ThemeResource DataGridColumnHeaderBackgroundBrush}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

Declaring the following has no effect:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderBackgroundBrush" Color="Orange" />
```

What is more confusing is that I'm still able to change the **foreground** color, with the following:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderForegroundBrush" Color="Red" />
```

If I was to guess, I would expect either the `Storyboard` / `ColorAnimation` sections are overriding it.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this issue by using the Nuget package [Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid 5.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/5.1.0). It's the latest version.

I found that if I use the [Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid 5.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/5.0.0), I did not face this issue. So, as a workaround, please try to install the [DataGrid 5.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/5.0.0) package.

I've helped you report this issue on Github [issue](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/2955).